# Does this Repeating Sequence Converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following sequence converge?

$a_n = \{1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, ...\}$

If not, could you please explain why?

(My thought is that it would converge to zero, since it's 1/n... but then it just goes to 1 again, so it maybe doesn't converge?...)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not converges. Because every $\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$-th element is 1, and every $\frac{n^2+n+4}{2}$-th element is $\frac12$.

Therefore there exist two converging subsequences, but their limits are not equal.

Because of the property of converging sequences, your sequence does not converge.

Comment: +1 As well as subsequences  converging to $\frac1k$ for every positive integer $k$, there are subsequences converging to $0$